# Настройка простого persistence.xml файла

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

При настройке получаю ошибку , добавил скрин шот !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http//java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="EmployeesTesting" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>Employee</class>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> ???? I got error here
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Данная ошибка в моём xml файле! В чём проблемма ?

[image: Ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если перевести текст ошибки на русский, то поймете в чем ошибка.

Comment: Оукей, таких ответов бы побольше! А если сказать сразу в чём ошибка ?

Comment: нода class должна быть после provider.